how to Extract Pdf comments into fdf format into text file thru running a cmd/bat file?
I have lost a bat file created by someone and hope to find some expert to help on this. We used to save the pdf file to fdf format and click on the bat file, it will automatically extract the comments in the pdf into .txt file. Thereafter we can copy these comments into the excel column that we created under 'comments'
anyone know how to create this bat file?
thank you in advance.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You could try cpdf -list-annotations in.pdf to do it directly from the PDF. Or, if that doesn't work, the more modern cpdf -list-annotations-json in.pdf (but then you would need to process the JSON. Might be easier than processing FDF though).

Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

hi all, thank you for the response. sorry DavidPostill, new user and thus unaware cannot ask for tips on free script/code writing service. K J, i have lost the file and the user has left the company hence unable to find out what text programmable method he used. is there any other website i can seek advise on free script/code service?
